# How to calculate the cosine similarity betwen list to lists?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

a = np.array([3, 45, 7, 2])
b = np.array([[2, 54, 13, 15], [2, 54, 13, 14], [2, 54, 13, 13]])

cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

but it fails. The idea is to calculate the cosine similarity of `a` over `b`, and get a list like this:

```
[0.97..., 0.97..., 0.97...]
```

Can I do this briefly or I need use `for`?

Comment: `b @ a / (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1))`, the example are `np.array` not `list`. Or `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(b, [a])`, you can also check `numpy` implementations with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a couple things: first, when using `dot()`, the last dimension of the first array needs to match the second-to-last dimension of the second array, so in your case what you probably want is `dot(a, b.T)`. Then, in order to compute the norm of each constituent array within `b` instead of computing the norm of `b` as a matrix, you need `norm(b, axis=1)`. Putting those together, you probably should use `dot(a, b.T) / (norm(a) * norm(b, axis=1))`.